# Wordpress - Why is the total page number ("All") greater than the sum of "Published"?

Tags: wordpress

I dont know if this is the right place to ask but i will try.When I am in my page menu, I see the following numbers:

All (120) | Published (80)

I first thought of a plugin or theme conflict. For this I also deactivated all plugins and used the default theme (Twenty*). But the problem does not disappear.

How is this possible? Why is "All" more than the published?
Can it be that even if I delete pages permanently they do not go away? Because have deleted a lot of pages.

I currently use the Divi theme. I also use a translation plugin "Polylang". However, I counted the number of pages in both languages and there are only 80 pages (40 for one language and 40 for the other).

Comment: "All" also counts the posts/pages in the trash and unpublished ones (drafts, private)

Comment: The problem is that i dont have any posts/pages in the trash and unpublished ones (drafts, private). All post/pages in the trash, has been deleted permanently.